# Objective-C regex to extract code + email from deeplink://domain/1242-4242-AAFF/joe@email.com

Tags: objective-c, regex

As specified in the title, I'm trying to write a regex to extract `1242-4242-AAFF` and, separately, `joe@email.com` from:

```
deeplink://domain/1242-4242-AAFF/joe@email.com
```

Here's what I wrote:

```
        NSError *error;
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                      regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/([A-Z-]{14})/?(.*)?"
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                      error:&error];
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:[url absoluteString]
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [url absoluteString].length)];
        if (match) {
            NSLog(@"here is the match from the absolute url %@", match);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
```

The match comes back null, and there is also no error. I thought `(A-Z-){14}` should  identify any code of the desired form XXXX-XXXX-XXXX where the X's can be numbers or capital letters. Am I going wrong there?

Comment: Why use a regex for this? Just get the index of the last two `/` characters and extract the corresponding substrings.

Comment: @rmaddy you have a good point, but I'd still like to know the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Z-]{14}` is only going to match some combination of 14 uppercase letters and dashes. No numbers.

You probably want to change that to `[0-9A-F-]{14}`. That will match any 14 hex digits and dashes.

Better yet, use `[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}` to match `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX`.

Answer (score 0):

To add something to @rmaddy answer, you could use the following, that adds a basic email address validation:

`([0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4})/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})`